# SQL Join based on two different date columns

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, inner-join

Given that I have these two following tables:

level_table

| id | level_date | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 2021-05 | C |
| 300 | 2020-04 | C |
| 300 | 2019-08 | C |
| 300 | 2022-06 | C |
| 300 | 2019-02 | C |
| 300 | 2018-01 | C |
| 300 | 2023-05 | C |
| 300 | 2021-11 | C |
| 300 | 2021-09 | C |
| 300 | 2021-04 | C |

protocol_table

| id | protc_date | protc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 2021-03 | 1 |
| 300 | 2018-04 | 2 |
| 300 | 2021-08 | 3 |
| 300 | 2020-06 | 4 |
| 300 | 2019-01 | 5 |
| 300 | 2022-03 | 6 |
| 300 | 2019-05 | 7 |
| 300 | 2023-05 | 8 |
| 300 | 2019-06 | 9 |
| 300 | 2018-01 | 10 |

I'd like to create a third that would be the inner join of those two, on the condition that the level_date has to be <= protc_date, and the level_date has to be the max_value of that given ID, respecting the first condition.

So in this example, my desired output would be the following:

tbl_join

| id | level_date | level | protc_date | protc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 2020-04 | C | 2021-03 | 1 |
| 300 | 2018-01 | C | 2018-04 | 2 |
| 300 | 2021-05 | C | 2021-08 | 3 |
| 300 | 2020-04 | C | 2020-06 | 4 |
| 300 | 2018-01 | C | 2019-01 | 5 |
| 300 | 2021-11 | C | 2022-03 | 6 |
| 300 | 2019-02 | C | 2019-02 | 7 |
| 300 | 2023-05 | C | 2023-05 | 8 |
| 300 | 2019-02 | C | 2019-06 | 9 |
| 300 | 2018-01 | C | 2018-01 | 10 |

How can I create a query to perform this operation?

What i've tried so far is this query below, however it does not return me the desired output.

```
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.protc_date,
       t2.protc,
FROM level_table as t1
INNER JOIN protocol_table as t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE (t1.level_date <= t2.protc_date
    AND t1.level_date = (
        SELECT MAX(level_date)
        FROM level_table as t1
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
    )
```

This query has returned me only one row, where it has the max(level_date) of my whole table, and not the max(level_date) for each protc and id.

| id | level_date | level | protc_date | protc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 2023-05 | C | 2023-05 | 8 |

Comment: You appear to have not actually asked a question - why can't you join your tables as described?

Comment: I apologize. I've corrected the question.

Comment: It's really confusing to use the same alias `t1` twice.

Comment: What is the datatype of `level_date` and `protc_date`? You can't compare this date format as strings. It should be `YYYY-MM` or `YYYY/MM`.

Comment: Both are date types. I've made the required adjustments.

Comment: @JoSSte No they don't, because it's a correlated subquery. And it makes no sense to group by the same column you're aggregating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0.13 or higher, I would recommend rewriting the query to use a [*lateral join*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html); this simplifies the query and makes it more efficient, because it avoids opening the level table multiple times, as in your current code (once in the join, and another in a correlated subquery).

```
select l.*, p.protc_date, p.protc
from protocol_table p
cross join lateral (
    select l.*
    from level_table l
    where l.id = p.id and l.level_date <= p.protc_date
    order by l.level_date desc 
    limit 1
) l
```

The subquery in the lateral join correlates the level table to the each row of the protocol table, sorts matching records by descending date and retains the top record only - which is then available in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery is not "respecting the first condition" -- it doesn't restrict to `level_date <= protc_date`.

```
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.protc_date,
       t2.protc
FROM level_table as t1
INNER JOIN protocol_table as t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE (t1.level_date <= t2.protc_date
    AND t1.level_date = (
        SELECT MAX(level_date)
        FROM level_table as t1
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t1.level_date <= t2.protc_date)
    )
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mh6pcyYEiufiBBkCj66tmL/0)